# XNA development tutorials

Tags: c#, xna

Can anybody guide me about where can I get the basic starter tutorials for developing using XNA framework?

Comment: So many answers here for XNA 3.0, not 4.0

Comment: The OP never specified a version. And the topic is 'XNA', not 'XNA 4'.

Answer (score 16):

(Silly that I can only post one link as a "new user")

If you haven't already looked through it, the XNA Creator's Club has quite a bit of resources: 
http://creators.xna.com/en-US/education/

Also, the first result when you search Google for "xna shader tutorials" has links to some great tutorials to learn Shader programming for XNA.

First result when you search Google for "xna development site" has a few tutorials in their Tutorial tab.

Good luck!  (Sorry again for the lack of links.)

Comment: http://forums.xna.com/forums/t/27849.aspx and http://www.xnadevelopment.com/ respectively.

Answer (score 16):

I grew up with [Riemers.net](http://www.riemers.net/) - very nice tutorial site covering everything form basics (drawing Your first triangle) to advanced techniques (HLSL). In every tutorial You create a cool application, like a flight simulator for example.

Comment: These tutorials are very good, they don't focus too much on C# details and instead focus on the more important game-development aspects. Good for people who already know C#.

Comment: +1. Some parts could be handled better but overall an excellent learning resource. Very informative, packed full of interesting information.

Answer (score 3):

And here's a long list of blogs and sites related to XNA:
http://creators.xna.com/en-US/community_resources

Answer (score 3):

I have found the videos at [3D Buzz](http://www.3dbuzz.com/vbforum/sv_videonav.php?fid=0ff61b695c6bdfd1a409d4e94c13ae33) to be of very high quality.

Answer (score 2):

http://sgtconker.com is a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

I really highly recommend digging through [How To Make A Game (For Free In XNA)](http://www.doolwind.com/blog/how-to-make-a-game-for-free-in-xna/) by Doolwind. Excellent read with terrific links :)

Answer (score 1):

I enjoyed these high quality beginner tutorials.
http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/xna-tutorials

Answer (score 1):

I found [XNA Development: Tutorials for the masses](http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials.shtml) to be absolutely great. It covers basic things well - sprites, moving them, firing things, scrolling backgrounds, and comes with full source. The other material, on game states and other bits, are equally good.

The other thing I found  useful, but definitely at a slightly more advanced level, is Nick Gravelyn's tutorial for Alien Aggressors. It's a full featuring Space Invaders/Galaga clone.
I cannot find it, since his site's been taken down. But it was in pdf form and a great read if anyone can find.

Answer (score 1):

[XNA 4.0 Game Development by Example - Kurt Jaegers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1849690669)

Answer (score 0):

I found a blog on one of Microsofts sites to be quite useful http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pavely/

Helped me start developing a 2D game.

Answer (score 0):

There’s a 2D tile-based RPG tutorial for XNA4 out there. Seems the guy always keeps it up to date, so there might also be a version for future versions of XNA.

http://xnagpa.net/xna4rpg.php