# Best Tutorials for Learning XNA (VB 2010)

Tags: xna-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XNA development tutorials](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1245/xna-development-tutorials)

I'm looking for some good tutorials for XNA 4.0 (with VS 2010) using VB. I've been looking on google and can't find much that's useful. So does anyone know some good sites or videos I can watch to teach me the basics. I know how to write in VB so just the basics and tips for XNA. I am hoping to make a 2D game.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use C# for programming XNA since is the primary language for it.